# How to compare columnA in 1st record and columnB in 2nd record of a same table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

For example

| Name | Start_Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2020/01/01 | 2020/2/3 |
| ABC | 2020/2/4 | 2020/5/4 |

how to compare end_date of first record with start_date of 2nd recod

desired result:

| Name | Start_Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2020/01/01 | 2020/5/4 |

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Based on what you said, it looks like just min and max of each column. But it is not a safe assumption I think. You need to provide a bit more detail on the requirement. Did you mean combine them, rather than compare them? If it is combine, what are the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Name , MIN (Start_Date) , Max(End_date) from tbl
group by Name
```

This way you can find Names minimal start and max end times.